# content script - window.location.href = url_b; lands on about:blank page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my content script
    *var url_b = 'chrome-extension://abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv/page_b.html';

    window.location.href = url_b;* 
takes me to about:blank instead of chrome file
'chrome-extension://abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv/page_b.html' url is valid and works when opened in a new tab

same code if url_b = 'www.gmail.com'
takes me to gmail. works fine.

to reproduce.
1.open gmail.com in a tab
2.open console and command in 'window.location.href = chrome-extension://any sample file'
3.about:blank opens
4.run step 2 again
5.sample page opens

Comment: Have you added `page_b.html` to [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources)?

Comment: After adding page_b.html to web_accessible_resources it worked. Thanks a lot Rob W.